# verify that Zarr has been fully installed by running the test suite

Tags: python, terminal, pytest, macos-catalina, zarr

suggested cmds on Zarr:

```
$ pip install pytest
$ python -m pytest -v --pyargs zarr
```

what I tried to make it work:

```
$ pip3 install pytest (succeeded)
$ python3.7 pytest -v --pyargs zarr
```

Error I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pytest': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I checked the path, and indeed the file `'pytest'` is somewhere else. Not sure if I may (and how) to change the path or location to make the cmd run

Comment: Welcome toStackoverflow. Make sure to get aquainted with the guidelines onhowtopost questions. We have formatted your code but you should do this yourself. Also, be clear on what you are asking help with.

Answer (score 0):

issued solved with terminal window -zsh and not -bash